# row span with XWPFTable

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

how can I merge cells over 2 or more rows (row span) using XWPFTable in POI in Java?

I know how merge cells in one row but i have no idea how do it and i don't find any example of this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you ALREADY hava a table with N rows and M columns, and you want to merge some cells, say "B5" and "B6" (i know you mean Word, not Excel, but just to describe the cell coordinates in the same way)

Comment: Or, you want to create a table from scratch?

Comment: it doesn't really matter, i can do both create or update table.   Yes, i want merge cells like B5 and B6.

Comment: why i asked it is that if you want to build the table from scratch, then you can just build your table cell-by-cell and when you want your BIG CELL to be created, you can try inserting even a new TABLE inside the old one. Does it interest you that i spend some time trying it and then will post the code?   But if you have a strong constraint to update the existing table, than i don't know how to do this row span

Comment: thanks, it is good point to start with. On the other hand, I find the method which look like helpfull, but i have no idea how to use it  table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(CTVMerge arg);

Comment: found it! you have found the first half of the answer. Teamwork =)

Comment: Please see if this is useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209863/apache-poi-merge-cells-from-a-table-in-a-word-document

--
Regards,
RRPV.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it! Thanks to your own comment about `getCTTc().getTcPr()...` and [this site](http://beginner-mercenary.blogspot.fr/2014/02/docx-apache-poi_12.html), here is a little program to test **vertical merge:**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STMerge;


public class VerticalMerge {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows = 5;
        int cols = 5;

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable(rows, cols);

        fillTable(table);

        mergeCellsVertically(table, 3, 1, 3);

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("vertical merge.docx");
            document.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void fillTable(XWPFTable table) {
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.getNumberOfRows(); rowIndex++) {
            XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(rowIndex);

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.getTableCells().size(); colIndex++) {
                XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
                cell.addParagraph().createRun().setText(" cell " + rowIndex + colIndex + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void mergeCellsVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {

        for (int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {

            XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);

            if ( rowIndex == fromRow ) {
                // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
                cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
            } else {
                // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
                cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For the moment, it doesn't concatenate text in merged cells, but i have an idea and will update this answer soon.  Good luck!

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot :). It is not necessary to concatenate text in merged cells what is more for me it event should not do this to be consistent with POI HSSF(XSSF) which simply override merged cells.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks to you for a nice question and a hint, without which i wouldn't have found an answer. I also tried to merge some blocks of cells, say, 2x3 cells, but the effect was as if i used two separate vertical merge over 1x3 vertical block. Probably, to delete the "walls" between those blocks, we have to do a **horizontal** merge after. Well, depending on your task, you can test some "2D merge", etc. Good luck, @blazej!

Comment: Hi, Excellent solution! It works wonderfully. I want to add that, the way to handle merging the text in each cell within a vertical merge range, is to loop through each of the cells to be merged, then loop through all paragraphs and runs and grab the text from each run.