# Apache POI merge cells from a table in a Word document

Tags: java, apache, merge, apache-poi, cells

I need to have a table with the cells on the first and second row merged.

Something like this:

Image of table (I can't post pics) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAO6j.png

I have been reviewing all the questions related to this topic and I have found some answers for applying  grid span to the cells, but I couldn't find a real solution.

Here is the code I have from examples obtained from google and from this site:

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFTable table = document.createTable(7, 2);

    fillTable(table);

    XWPFTableCell cellRow1 = table.getRow(0).getCell(0);
    XWPFTableCell cellRow2 = table.getRow(1).getCell(0);

    cellRow1.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
    cellRow1.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
    cellRow1.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(2L));

    cellRow2.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
    cellRow2.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
    cellRow2.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(2L));

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Table.docx");
    doc.write(out);
    out.close();
```

What I get from this code is the following:

[image]

I tried to remove the "extra" cells with `table.getRow(0).removeCell(1);` but it didn't work, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It seems xml has to be removed as well:

```
 XWPFTableCell removed = tableRow.getCell(idx);
 removed.getCTTc().newCursor().removeXml();
 tableRow.removeCell(idx);
```

Comment: it did work, thank you very much I just needed to removed like this:

            `cellRow = table3.getRow(0).getCell(2);
            cellRow.getCTTc().newCursor().removeXml();
            cellRow = table3.getRow(0).getCell(1);
            cellRow.getCTTc().newCursor().removeXml();`

Comment: Need to remove the cell from the table before removing the XML..else NPE happens

Answer (score 4):

To merge horizontally/vertically you need to create 2 CTHMerge and use the setVal:

- one for the cells that you will remain (STMerge.RESTART);
- a second one for the merged cells (STMerge.CONTINUE);

a) example of a **horizontal** merge for a 2x2 table:

|___________|___________| --> |___________ ___________|
|___________|___________| --> |___________ ___________|

```
// First Row
CTHMerge hMerge = CTHMerge.Factory.newInstance();
vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge);
table.getRow(1).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge);

// Secound Row cell will be merged/"deleted"
CTHMerge hMerge1 = CTHMerge.Factory.newInstance();
hMerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge1);
table.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge1);
```

b) example of a **vertical** merge:

```
 // First Row
CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge);
table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge);

 // Secound Row cell will be merged 
CTVMerge vmerge1 = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
table.getRow(1).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge1);
table.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge1);
```

Comment: That's a neat solution. However, if you are planning to convert docx to other formats later, keep in mind, that many libaries do not support this tag

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid creating the extra cells, instead of removing cells after the merge. It requires adding rows and cells sequentially (instead of using `document.createTable()`)

For your example it would be:

1. Create first rows with 1 cell, set text
2. Create next row, and in it create new cell, set text
3. Create next rows and set text
4. Merge