# How to merge cells horizontally using apache-poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I  get to do a vertically merged using this function:

```
private static void mergeCellsVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int      fromRow, int toRow) {
    for (int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
        if ( rowIndex == fromRow ) {
            // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
                cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
        } else {
            // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
        }
    }
}
```

but I can't do the horizontal merge with similar function:

```
private static void mergeCellsHorizontally(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromCol, int toCol) {

    for (int colIndex = fromCol; colIndex <= toCol; colIndex++) {

        XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(colIndex);

        if ( colIndex == fromCol ) {
            // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewHMerge().setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
            cell.setText("hola");
        } else {
            // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewHMerge().setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
            cell.setText("adios");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing it at a sheet-level? 
See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716032/merging-cells-in-excel-using-apache-poi#18717238

Comment: Please describe what is the problem. Is an error thrown? If not, what occurs otherwise? This approach does not check if the `CTTc` objects already contain a `TcPr` element. So probably multiple `TcPr` elements will be appended. This will not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647624/how-to-colspan-a-table-in-word-with-apache-poi/34663420#34663420 for another approach.

Comment: You probably need to check how Word stores this in the XML and then do the same with the low-level API of POI

Comment: Currently, the solution with  HMerge is working fine, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209863/apache-poi-merge-cells-from-a-table-in-a-word-document

Answer (score 1):

### The solution is:

```
  setCellSpan(row.getCell(2), 5);
   CTRow ctRow = row.getCtRow(); 
    CTTc[] ctTcs = new CTTc[4]; // las colunas que quedan
    for(int y = 0; y < ctRow.sizeOfTcArray(); y++) { 
       if(y != 4 && y != 5  && y != 6 && y != 7){ //Las columnas que desaparecen
    ctTcs[y] = ctRow.getTcArray(y);
} }ctRow.setTcArray(ctTcs);
```

where:

```
public static void setCellSpan(XWPFTableCell cell, int span) {
    if (cell.getCTTc().getTcPr() == null) {
        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
    }
    if (cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan() == null) {
        cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().addNewGridSpan();
    }
    cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf((long) span));
}
```