# Apache POI (Word) merge cells from table

Tags: merge, ms-word, apache-poi, cell

I need help with apache POI lib.

A final version of table should looks like that:

[image]

and now I'm able to get this:

[image]

From some reason I'm not able to merge this cells on the begin and on the end.

Below is code which is merging cells(position: 1):

```
private static void mergeVerticalCells(int maxCellPosition, XWPFTableRow restartRow, XWPFTableRow... continueRows) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= maxCellPosition ; i++) {
            CTVMerge vmergeRestart = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
            vmergeRestart.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
            restartRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmergeRestart);
        }

        for (XWPFTableRow row : continueRows) {
            CTVMerge vmergeContinue = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
            vmergeContinue.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
            for (int i = 0 ; i<= maxCellPosition ; i++) {
                row.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmergeContinue);
            }
        }
    }
```

[Here is link where I found this solution to merge cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209863/apache-poi-merge-cells-from-a-table-in-a-word-document)

Can somebody show me what I'm doing wrong?